# What is the real dimension of a manifold?

Tags: general-topology

This is just hypothetic: If I'm given a function $f(x,y,z)$ like:

$f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 -z^2 +c$

The theory proclaims that the dimension is: $\underbrace{\texttt{number of columns}}_{N} - \underbrace{\texttt{number of rows}}_{r}\:$  of $D(f)$. In this case:

$D(f) = [2x \quad 2y \quad 2z]$, hence $\texttt{dim}  = 3-1 = 2$

This correspond with the plot: For $c = -1$ I'm getting a hyperboloid.

Now to my question: If I choose $x, y$ or $z$ to be $0$ I'm still getting a $\text{3-D-shape}$. If I'm not understanding the theorem wrong the dimension has to be reduced however. Maybe it's the way I plot. I'm doing this with Matlab:

```
f = @(x,y,z) x.^2 + y.^2 - 0.^2-1;

fimplicit3(f)
```

Her I set $z$ to $0$, but it shows me the surface of a cylinder still...

Comment: Your question is not very precise. I think what you mean is this: Given a function $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$. For which $c$ is the set $\{ (x,y,z) \mid f(x,y,z) = c \}$ a manifold and what is its dimension? You should also add  the definition of a manifold (is a **smooth** manifold?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of columns is still 3, $D(f) = [2x \quad 2y \quad 0]$. Just in this case one of the columns is 0. The function is still a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $D(f)$ has 3 columns and 1 row.

Either way, you can still get strange examples like $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, where the dimension should be 2 but the 0 set is just a point. Dimension=(number of columns)-(number of rows) not always works. Although it will work most of the times (when there are no self intersections) in points where $D(f)\neq 0$.